# sinatra rest-client etag

Tags: sinatra, etag, rest-client

My goal is to address "lost update problem" (see http://www.w3.org/1999/04/Editing/) in PUT operations.
I am using sinatra, and as a client I use rest_client. How I can check if it works? My client always return 200 code. Am I using arguments of calling it correctly? (PUT itself works)

sinatra code:

```
put '/players/:id' do |id|
    etag 'something'
    if Player[id].nil? then
        halt 404
    end
    begin
        data = JSON.parse(params[:data])
        pl = Player[id]
        pl.name = data['name']
        pl.position = data['position']
        if pl.save
            "Resource modified."
        else
            status 412
            redirect '/players'   
        end

    rescue Sequel::DatabaseError   
        409 #Conflict - The request was unsuccessful due to a conflict in the state of the resource.
    rescue Exception => e 
        400
        puts e.message   
    end
end
```

client invocation:

```
player = {"name" => "John Smith", "position" => "def"}.to_json

RestClient.put('http://localhost:4567/players/1', {:data => player, :content_type => :json, :if_none_match => '"something"'}){ |response, request, result, &block|
    p response.code.to_s + " " + response
}
```

I tried already to put :if_none_match => "something", I tried :if_match. Nothing changes. 
How I can put headers into RestClient request? 
How to obtain sth different than 200 status? (ie 304 not modified)?

Answer (score 0):

Your payload and headers are in the same hash. You have to specify the headers for `RestClient` in second hash. Try:

```
player = {"name" => "John Smith", "position" => "def"}.to_json
headers = {:content_type => :json, :if_none_match => '"something"'}

RestClient.put('http://localhost:4567/players/1', {:data => player}, headers) do |response, request, result, &block|
    p response.code.to_s + " " + response
end
```

I am not sure if `RestClient` translates the headers correctly. If the above doesn't work, try it with:

```
headers = {'Content-Type' => :json, 'If-None-Match' => '"something"'}
```